# Difference between abuse and misuse

Tags: phrase-requests

What is the correct phrase to use when you call the police multiple times for less than urgent matters? Misuse of resources???

Comment: This could be misuse or abuse. Generally, abuse is the stronger term and implies causing damage or harm in some way; misuse just implies not using something correctly.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please see also: [ell.se]

Answer (score 3):

In general:
Abuse is used for knowingly taking advantage or doing something bad.

Misuse is used for making a mistake or unknowingly doing something wrong.

Of course there's exceptions, but that's the most straightforward way to explain the words in this context.